# Does java have a a fast web deployment framework?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, asp.net-mvc

Something similar to Ruby on Rails, mean stack, or Asp.net MVC.

I tried using Maven, but when I created a new webapp the template app doesn't even run. I've tried looking into struts or spring as I want for the app to be MVC, but that doesn't seem like it's exactly what I want.

Has java not caught up to the convention over configuration programming paradigm ?

**Edit**

To clarify as original question was a bit ambiguous:

I want to have a working web app which I would be to  expand from. Similar to Microsofts MVC you create a new web project and you start with controllers, basic crud, the annotations library for data validation, required fields etc, and something like the entity framework which simplifies the database access layer.

I guess my question is: *Is there  a process you can deploy a working web app in a few minutes, and if so what is it?*

Comment: What do you mean with "web deployment framework"? And how fast is "fast"? What kind of "fast" do you mean? What happens when you try to run the maven webapp? What is it that you exactly want to have/achieve?

Comment: I want to have a working web app which I can expand from there. Similar to Microsofts MVC you create a new web project and you have already have your controllers basic crud and the annotations library for data validation, required fields etc, and something like the entity framework. I would imagine java would have something like this since everything is moving in this direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Boot sounds like what you're looking for. Take a look at http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot

This is Spring's "convention over configuration" web application project. With this you're able to start an embedded tomcat web application complete with dependency injection and component scanning by simply adding a few annotations to a one line main method.